# Каким образом Iterable может хранить объекты?

Tags: java

Есть сигнатура метода: `Iterable<Task> incoming(Iterable<Task> tasks, Date start, Date end).`

Метод предназначен для хранения `Task`ов которые выполняются в промежутке между `start` и `end`.

*Вопрос: Каким образом работает `Iterable`. Что хранит?*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Iterable` - это интерфейс. Он в себе ничего не хранит, он предоставляет собой *поведение*. В данном случае, поведение - это перебор элементов. Это если совсем кратко. Рекомендую почитать [статью с хабры](http://habrahabr.ru/post/30444/) на эту тему.

Сигнатура метода `Iterable<Task> incoming(Iterable<Task> tasks, Date start, Date end)` говорит о том, что в качестве первого аргумента будет поставляться коллекция, параметризованная типом `Task` и которая имплементирует интерфейс `Iterable`. Далее у этой коллекции можно будет взять `iterator`, т.к. этот метод объявлен в интерфейсе `Iterable`, с помощью которого можно будет обойти пришедшую коллекцию

Answer (score 3):

`Iterable` - это интерфейс, и он говорит только о поведении. В данном случае имеется ввиду его метод `iterator()`, возвращающий итератор. Это значит, что класс, имплементирующий данный интерфейс, должен иметь реализацию указанного выше метода.

Работать с указанной вами сигнатурой просто - надо на вход метода передать все что угодно, лишь бы оно было `Iterable`.
Самое простое - например, использовать `public static <E> ArrayList<E> newArrayList(Iterator<? extends E> elements)` из  [com.google.common.collect.Lists , guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries)